# SQL Join over two tables

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

here is my problem:

I have two tables. Every entry of table A has several entries in table B matched over an ID. I now want to get all entries of table A with one data entry of table B - the one with the highest ID in this table.

> Table A has an ID
>
> Table B has an own ID and ID_OF_TABLE_A (for the relation between both)

Table A has one to many relation to Table B. I want all Entries of Table A, matched with the one with the highest ID out of B. Is there any way to realize this in an SQL Statement? I tried all kinds of joins since I need the information of that matched entry in the outcome of the select.

Comment: Several right answers below. All of them work great - some more complicated than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID_OF_TABLE_A
WHERE b.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tableB c WHERE b.ID = c.ID)
```

Comment: I used this one and it worked perfectly. All others seemed to work too. So many good answers, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM tableA a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT b.* 
                 FROM tableB b 
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_OF_TABLE_A, MAX(ID) bID 
                             FROM tableB 
                             GROUP BY ID_OF_TABLE_A
                           ) c ON b.ID_OF_TABLE_A = c.ID_OF_TABLE_A AND b.ID = c.bID
                ) AS b ON a.ID = b.ID_OF_TABLE_A;
```

Comment: as b is a bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inline view where you filter the rows you need from table b with the help of the grouping clause and max function like so:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a
join (
    select max(id) as id_b_max, id_a
    from b
    group by id_a
) b
on a.id = b.id_a;
```

Tested with:

```
create table a(id int);

create table b(id int, id_a int);

insert a values (1);

insert b values(1, 1);
insert b values(2, 1);
insert b values(3, 1);
```

Comment: Did not declared the FK object itself but still the answer is valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id, max(b.id)
from  table_a a join table_b b on a.id = b.table_a_id
group by a.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. prefilter out the max id of the ID_OF_TABLE_A. and then join on that id.

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT max( ID ) AS id, ID_OF_TABLE_A 
                 FROM B
                 GROUP BY ID_OF_TABLE_A) AS grp_b 
        ON grp_b.ID_OF_TABLE_A = a.ID
    INNER JOIN B ON b.ID = grp_b.id
```